# date from ObjectID in Javascript

Tags: mongodb, ember.js

I'm evaluation Ember to use in one of my projects and needed to extract the Date information from the ObjectID provided by MongoDB. I went with a computed property as bellow:

```
created_at: Ember.computed(function() {
    var objid = this.get('_id');
    return new Date(parseInt(objid.substring(0,8), 16)*1000);
  }).property('_id')
```

I'm happy with that, just wanted to know if there is a better way to do it.. any thoughts?

thanks!

Comment: A computed property is what would probably be best here.

Comment: Not sure the `Ember.computed` bit is doing anything. My computed properties work fine just with `foo: function() { ... }.property('_id')` – or am I missing something?

Comment: The `Ember.computed` bit is necessary if prototype extensions were turned off. If they're on, it won't hurt but it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track.  As Martin suggested in his comment, you do not need to preface the function with Ember.computed().  The property() call will take care of that for you.  By doing both, you are making a computed property method out of a computed property method, which seems like it may cause problems.

Also consider marking the property as cacheable(), which will cause the function to only execute once when _id changes, as opposed to any time the method is called.

This seems like the ideal approach:

```
created_at: function() {
  var objid = this.get('_id');
  return new Date(parseInt(objid.substring(0,8), 16)*1000);
}.property('_id').cacheable()
```

Comment: `cacheable` is now the default.